# with no doubt at all

Tags: punctuation

Here's definition #5 of the word "positive" in Longman:

> 5 SURE [not before noun] very sure, **with no doubt at all** that something is right or true
>
> [['Positive' - Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/positive)]

Can I add a comma after "all"? Because "with no doubt at all" is a parenthetic expression, before and after which I think a comma is needed.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see it as parenthetic. I think _very sure_ and _with no doubt at all that something is right_ are two different phrases. Dictionary definitions often list words or phrases separated by commas.

Comment: Kate Bunting is right.  It's not parenthetic.  Your proposed change (the extra comma) would convert it so that it becomes parenthetic, and there wouldn't be any real difference in meaning, but currently it isn't.

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having other contextual information, I would say that you have a definite clause here. The noun phrase "no doubt at all "is being described by "**that something is right or true**".

When you have a definite clause, you don't use a comma.

Comment: The context is that it's a dictionary definition of _positive_!